# Chrome Extension message passing not receiving response

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get a simple message passing to work on chrome extension, but I'm not getting a response. I'm sending a message from popup.js to the content script and the content script should return a response.

My popup.js:

```
let myButton= document.getElementById('myButton');

myButton.onclick = function(){
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
      });
    });
  };
```

my content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("Message Received");
                console.log(request.greeting);
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      myFunction(sendResponse);
     return true; 
  });
  
  function myFunction(sendResponse)
  {
      console.log('Sending response');
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  }
```

In the console I'm getting the 'Sending response' message, but not the log after that in the popup.js

Comment: Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Thank you!  I feel like an idiot!